# can we use arr[key:value] in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In so many Javascript libraries and Angular plugin, I have seen the use of JS array like this:

```
var arr = ['size':20, 'Active', 'role':'user'];
```

(This is just an example how they use key and values)

I searched for javascript array but it looks different so how can we use this type of array?

Comment: `var arr = {'size':20, 'Active', 'role':'user'};` You are confusing yourself with an object and a plain array.

Comment: I know this is a JS Object i am more curious about the use of JS array in this style.

Comment: There is no such thing in JavaScript.

Comment: Array of objects? `var arr = [{"hi":1}{"hi":2}{"hi":3}]`

Comment: BTW, this will be an array of _what_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't write it like this because of the javascript syntax. You can still achieve this, but you shouldn't.

Long answer:

Arrays are considered as objects in Javascript. So you can do this for example :

```
var array = [];
array['size'] = 20;
console.log(array['size']);
```

It will work because the array works like any other objects. But you shouldn't do it. It will just confuse your code. Use a plain object to do that:

```
var obj = {'size':20, 'Active': undefined, 'role':'user'};
```